# Display & Video 360 - How to retrieve performances data without a report?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I'm using the google API for Display & Video 360 and try to get performances data on Line Items & Insertion Orders (CPA, budget spent, etc...). How can I retrieve that without having to manually create a report then download it through the API?

Thank you!